# preg_repalce matched partial data with correct regex

Tags: php, regex

```
$str = a b c;
$str = preg_replace("/a|b|c\","" $str);
```

above regex only matched a, b and c are excluded. At first I thought it was caused by the gobal thing, but after researched `preg_match` itself has default global enabled. So what has actually gone wrong?

Comment: `$str = "a b c";` - doing `$str = a b c;` should have thrown an parse error.

Comment: it would be `$str = preg_replace("/a|b|c/", "", $str);`

Comment: Doing `\"` is like asking PHP to escape the `"` - Do as Avinash showed you, along with the missing comma.

Comment: Why do you [repost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25959823/g-in-regex-using-preg-replace-of-php) with the same syntax errors but without actually trying it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need quotes around your string:

```
$str = "a b c";
```

...a comma between your replacement text and the source, and flip your closing RegEx slash to match your opening one:

```
$str = preg_replace("/a|b|c/", "", $str);
```

That will leave $str set to [space][space]

Answer (score 0):

A regex must be enclosed in delimeters. A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character. Usually you use `/` which has to be at the beginning and at the end of the regex string.

Also a string in php must be encased in either `"` or `'`.

Lastly you are missing a comma in the `preg_replace` function.

```
$str = "a b c";
$str = preg_replace("/a|b|c/", "", $str);
```